# Why isn't move constructor faster?

Tags: c++, performance, move, semantics, move-constructor

I have a very simple test case, with one *Geometry* class containing a very large std::vector. I am comparing the speed of copy/move constructors:

```
class Geometry
{
public:
    Geometry(size_t size) : m_data(size) {}

    Geometry(const Geometry& other) : m_data(other.m_data)
    { std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl; }

    Geometry(Geometry&& other) noexcept : m_data(std::move(other.m_data))
    { std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl; }

private:
    std::vector<double> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    Geometry geometry(1000000000);

    {
        ScopedTimer scopedTimer("copy constructor");
        Geometry geometry2(geometry);
    }

    {
        ScopedTimer scopedTimer("move constructor");
        Geometry geometry2(std::move(geometry));
    }
}
```

I was expecting the copy constructor to be very slow, and the move constructor to be virtually instantaneous, as it just needs to swap the handle to the underlying vector resources. However, this is not what I am observing here (ScopedTimer is just a simple timer based on std::chrono that returns the duration between its construction and destruction). Here is the output I am getting in release configuration (a similar trend is observed in debug configuration):

```
Copy constructor
6832 ms copy constructor
Move constructor
2605 ms move constructor
```

Move constructor is about three times faster, which is better, but not what I was expecting. Why isn't it faster than that? I was expecting the move constructor to be O(1). Why does it take longer with larger vector sizes? The code does not need to allocate anything, etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: it looks like you built the app in debug mode. those results are unrealistic for simple code like that.

Comment: `std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl;` can be quite expensive due to the `std::endl` flushing the stream. I don't expect it to be that expensive, but replace the `std::endl` with `'\n'` and see if it helps.

Comment: @user4581301 In a loop, sure, but it looks like it's called all of two times here.

Comment: For what it's worth, this takes forever and a half on my machine when compiled without optimization, but very little time with `-O3` applied. Instantiating the first `Geometry` object takes the bulk of the time, the other two are very quick, maybe <100ms.

Comment: Doing any kind of outputting during the benchmark code is introducing noise into your measurement. Track what you care about using the lightest possible implementation and only print the results at the end (after the last measurement). In this case, what's printed doesn't even matter, you could just do away with the printing all together.

Comment: I thought about that, but if that was the case, the trend would dissapear with larger vector sizes, as the output time becomes negligible. This is not what I am observing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are measuring vector destruction time. Without it move constructor takes no time even in debug mode:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

class ScopedTimer
{
    std::string m_text;
    ::std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start;
    public: ScopedTimer(::std::string const & text):
    m_text{text}, start{::std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()} {}

    public: void Report(void)
    {
        auto const end{::std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};
        ::std::cout << m_text << " " << ::std::chrono::duration_cast<::std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << ::std::endl;
    }
};


class Geometry
{
public:
    Geometry(size_t size) : m_data(size) {}

    Geometry(const Geometry& other) : m_data(other.m_data)
    { std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl; }

    Geometry(Geometry&& other) noexcept : m_data(std::move(other.m_data))
    { std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl; }

private:
    std::vector<double> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    Geometry geometry(1000000000);
    {
        ScopedTimer scopedTimer("copy constructor");
        {
            Geometry geometry2(geometry);
            scopedTimer.Report();
        }
        scopedTimer.Report();
    }
    {
        ScopedTimer scopedTimer("move constructor");
        {
            Geometry geometry2(std::move(geometry));
            scopedTimer.Report();
        }
        scopedTimer.Report();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Copy constructor
>   copy constructor 5099
>   copy constructor 6526
>   Move constructor
>   move constructor 0
>   move constructor 1319

Comment: haaaa. Makes perfect sense now, thanks! Here are the results for comparison...
Copy constructor: 3443 ms Move constructor: 0 ms

Comment: Not only that... OP also measures some lazily-executed initialization code. I made mctor case ~5000 times slower than cctor case simply by [running it first](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZIDzgY5K9WlYvUug) ;)

Comment: @C.M. Unfortunately wandbox does not work for me anymore, but won't running mctor first leave vector empty?

Comment: @VTT The wandbox code invokes UB (or something close to UB), you cannot use a moved vector like that.